# Can you complete the Cayo Perico heist without activating the alarm?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Spoiler I guess, if you haven't completed it.

So far I've been able to get just outside the lift in the main compound. Having only the mega armored guard and one last guard. Every time I kill the very last normal guard, the alarm sounds. Is it just coincidence every time, or will the alarm sound always?

Comment: My favorite approach is to go in through the tunnel, then west (there a two guards talking at one point, you can kill both when you are fast) sneaking along the walls to the cages (killing guards and camera on the way), then behind the panther's cage to the stairs to to office. However, once I have stealthily left the mansion and are back on the "big map", I just grab a car and break though the main checkpoint, making it as fast as possible to the western/main harbor where I steal a boat. I complete all three "disruption" preps before doing this, obviously. I'm too lazy to do a stealthy exit.

Comment: @Klaws What's your PB ? I've done it in 8:27 with some good RNG to begin with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqEzMbBMjEM (Also this is obviously my fav approach :D )

Comment: Never tried a speedrun; my "usual time" seems to be around 16 minutes. My current exit strategy is, after exiting the compound, to run left along the wall to the sea, jump into the water and swim away from the island (since I use the drainage tunnel approach, I have scuba gear and can evade enemies by swimming underwater; a good thing to do if I somehow managed to raise the alarm...). Sometimes I "liberate" a patrol boat; that's a bit faster than swimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most definitely possible to fully stealth the Cayo Perico heist, as seen in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUayNFp3igc) video. Most likely the reason you are triggering the alarm is that there is a camera out that is not visible on your minimap that has the guard in its vision.

Comment: I was actually triggering it when exploding the last chain for the main objective. It's million times easier with bolt cutters and a guard uniform. You can literally drive around the entire island, go into the main compound, kill 4 people till you get to the elevator, then on your way out kill another 1-3 again DRIVE out without being challenged and get on a boat.

Comment: The dome cameras are a major PITA. They don't have a vision cone (just like in real life, you cannot see where the camera inside is looking). But they are also not marked on the minimap, even though the location should be known after scouting out the target (it's pretty obvious, for example, that there is a camera inside the panther's cage). Apparently, Pavel is more concerned about marking secondary targets (useless if you go solo) than camera locations (immensely useful). Players also seem to think the same, as I have not yet seen any heist guide which shows the "hidden" cameras on a map.

Comment: @Klaws Interesting, I've never had a single problem with a hidden camera. But then again I'm always going for a guard uniform, ALWAYS

Comment: It appears that the dome cameras are irrelevant; they don't do anything (except that they fizzle when you shoot them, and this might alert a guard). I did two stealth runs now without disabling any dome camera (just the regular red ones on the minimap), and I could pass them without any issues. - -Of course, concentrating on the cameras made me accidentally bump into a guard...